# Find out what process registered a global hotkey? (Windows API)

Tags: delphi, winapi, hotkeys, registerhotkey

As far as I've been able to find out, Windows doesn't offer an API function to tell what application has registered a global hotkey (via RegisterHotkey). I can only find out that a hotkey is registered if RegisterHotkey returns false, but not who "owns" the hotkey.

In the absence of a direct API, could there be a roundabout way? Windows maintains the handle associated with each registred hotkey - it's a little maddening that there should be no way of getting at this information.

Example of something that likely wouldn't work: send (simulate) a registered hotkey, then intercept the hotkey message Windows will send to the process that registered it. First, I don't think intercepting the message would reveal the destination window handle. Second, even if it were possible, it would be a bad thing to do, since sending hotkeys would trigger all sorts of potentially unwanted activity from various programs.

It's nothing critical, but I've seen frequent requests for such functionality, and have myself been a victim of applications that register hotkeys without even disclosing it anywhere in the UI or docs.

(Working in Delphi, and no more than an apprentice at WinAPI, please be kind.)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Your question piqued my interest, so I've done a bit of digging and while, unfortunately I don't have a proper answer for you, I thought I'd share what I have.

I found this [example of creating keyboard hook (in Delphi)](http://groups.google.com/group/borland.public.delphi.winapi/msg/ceb5818acd623a24) written in 1998, but is compilable in Delphi 2007 with a couple of tweaks.

It's a DLL with a call to `SetWindowsHookEx` that passes through a callback function, which can then intercept key strokes: In this case, it's tinkering with them for fun, changing left cursor to right, etc. A simple app then calls the DLL and reports back its results based on a TTimer event. If you're interested I can post the Delphi 2007 based code.

It's well documented and commented and you potentially could use it as a basis of working out where a key press is going. If you could get the handle of the application that sent the key strokes, you could track it back that way. With that handle you'd be able to get the information you need quite easily.

Other apps have tried determining hotkeys by going through their Shortcuts since they can contain a Shortcut key, which is just another term for hotkey. However most applications don't tend to set this property so it might not return much. If you are interested in that route, Delphi has access to `IShellLink` COM interface which you could use to load a shortcut up from and get its hotkey:

```
uses ShlObj, ComObj, ShellAPI, ActiveX, CommCtrl;

procedure GetShellLinkHotKey;
var
  LinkFile : WideString;
  SL: IShellLink;
  PF: IPersistFile;

  HotKey : Word;
  HotKeyMod: Byte;
  HotKeyText : string;
begin
  LinkFile := 'C:\Temp\Temp.lnk';

  OleCheck(CoCreateInstance(CLSID_ShellLink, nil, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER, IShellLink, SL));

  // The IShellLink implementer must also support the IPersistFile
  // interface. Get an interface pointer to it.
  PF := SL as IPersistFile;

  // Load file into IPersistFile object
  OleCheck(PF.Load(PWideChar(LinkFile), STGM_READ));

  // Resolve the link by calling the Resolve interface function.
  OleCheck(SL.Resolve(0, SLR_ANY_MATCH or SLR_NO_UI));

  // Get hotkey info
  OleCheck(SL.GetHotKey(HotKey));

  // Extract the HotKey and Modifier properties.
  HotKeyText := '';
  HotKeyMod := Hi(HotKey);

  if (HotKeyMod and HOTKEYF_ALT) = HOTKEYF_ALT then
    HotKeyText := 'ALT+';
  if (HotKeyMod and HOTKEYF_CONTROL) = HOTKEYF_CONTROL then
    HotKeyText := HotKeyText + 'CTRL+';
  if (HotKeyMod and HOTKEYF_SHIFT) = HOTKEYF_SHIFT then
    HotKeyText := HotKeyText + 'SHIFT+';
  if (HotKeyMod and HOTKEYF_EXT) = HOTKEYF_EXT then
    HotKeyText := HotKeyText + 'Extended+';

  HotKeyText := HotKeyText + Char(Lo(HotKey));

  if (HotKeyText = '') or (HotKeyText = #0) then
    HotKeyText := 'None';

  ShowMessage('Shortcut Key - ' + HotKeyText);
end;
```

If you've got access to [Safari Books Online](http://my.safaribooksonline.com/), there is a [good section about working with shortcuts / shell links](http://my.safaribooksonline.com/0672321157/ch16lev1sec3) in the Borland Delphi 6 Developer's Guide by Steve Teixeira and Xavier Pacheco. My example above is a butchered version from there and [this site](http://delphicikk.atw.hu/listaz.php?id=2351&oldal=1).

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 139):

One possible way is to use the [**Visual Studio tool Spy++**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/spy-increment-help).

Give this a try:

1. If you don't already have it, install the [community edition of Visual Studio](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/vs/community/).  Spy++ is installed with it.
2. Run the tool (for me, it's in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\Common7\Tools\`. *Note: there is spyxx.exe (32-bit version) and spyxx_amd64.exe (64-bit version) - if you don't see anything in 64-bit use the 32-bit version (it only catches messages in same architecture)*
3. In the menu bar, select *Spy* -> *Log messages...* (or hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>M</kbd>)
4. Check *All Windows in System* in the *Additional Windows* frame
5. Switch to the *Messages* tab
6. Click the *Clear All* button
7. Select `WM_HOTKEY` in the listbox, or check *Keyboard* in *Message Groups* (if you're OK with more potential noise)
8. Click the *OK* button
9. Press the hotkey in question (<kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd>, for example)
10. Select the `WM_HOTKEY` line in the *Messages (All Windows)* window, right click, and select *Properties...* in the context menu
11. In the *Message Properties* dialog, click the *Window Handle* link (this will be the handle for the window that received the message)
12. Click the *Synchronize* button on the *Window Properties* dialog.  This will show the window in the main Spy++ window treeview (if it's windows itself or some popup application it shows nothing).
13. On the *Window Properties* dialog, select the *Process* tab
14. Click the *Process ID* link.  This will show you the process (In my <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> case: `EXPLORER`)

Comment: Great answer! Just a note that **the 64-bit version of Spy++ catches only messages for 64-bit applications**, so if you don't see the `WM_HOTKEY` message in the _Message log_ after pressing the hotkey, you may need to run the 32-bit version of Spy++.

Comment: In step 8 it doesn't ask for hotkey, messages window keeps staying empty after pressing any hotkey. Used 32 and 64-bits versions from https://github.com/westoncampbell/SpyPlusPlus (in Windows 10).

Comment: Suggestion: add to the answer that you can get the latest version of SpyPlusPlus from official sources by downloading the community edition of Visual Studio at https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/vs/community/ (I cannot edit the answer myself ...)

Comment: @MichalBernhard can you please expand (by editing the answer) on how to find this tool after installing [this](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=56046)? I searched my whole C: for `spyxx` and nothing.

Comment: Hi all, updating this thread for the VS studio 2022 installation, the spyxx is now at C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\Common7\Tools and FYI, it worked for me using spyxx_amd64.exe on win10 (and find out a rogue stackbrowser  capture my firefox's hotkeys like crtl+w )

Comment: Fantastic! And I found MS Edge is resetting my clipboard :(

Comment: Thanks. Also, how the heck did you know about this convoluted process.. :D

Comment: I knew this is how global hotkeys worked and that Spy++ can snoop window messages.  I'm just glad such a tool exists.

Comment: Thank you so much, I did not stand a chance in the world to find the culprit otherwise. Lenovo Display Control Center was capturing Right Alt + E (even though it's displayed as CTRL + ALT + E) and preventing me from typing "é" using a US International, Alt Gr dead keys keyboard layout. Disabling the shortcuts for the Lenovo app fixed it.

Comment: If you use a non-Community version of Visual Studio (tested with VS2022 Enterprise) then you can install spy++ by opening Visual Studio Installer, by selecting the Individual Components tab, and then selecting the following components. 
Under Debugging and testing, select C++ profiling tools
Under Development activities, select C++ core features.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/how-to-start-spy-increment?view=vs-2022

Answer (score 11):

After some research, it appears that you'd need to get access to the internal structure that MS uses to store the hotkeys.  ReactOS has a clean room implementation that implements the `GetHotKey` call by iterating an internal list and extracting the hotkey that matches the parameters to the call.

Depending on how close ReactOS' implementation is to the MS implementation, you may be able to poke around in memory to find the structure, but that's over my head...

```c
BOOL FASTCALL
GetHotKey (UINT fsModifiers,
           UINT vk,
           struct _ETHREAD **Thread,
           HWND *hWnd,
           int *id)
{
   PHOT_KEY_ITEM HotKeyItem;

   LIST_FOR_EACH(HotKeyItem, &gHotkeyList, HOT_KEY_ITEM, ListEntry)
   {
      if (HotKeyItem->fsModifiers == fsModifiers &&
            HotKeyItem->vk == vk)
      {
         if (Thread != NULL)
            *Thread = HotKeyItem->Thread;

         if (hWnd != NULL)
            *hWnd = HotKeyItem->hWnd;

         if (id != NULL)
            *id = HotKeyItem->id;

         return TRUE;
      }
   }

   return FALSE;
}
```

I presume [this thread on sysinternals](http://forum.sysinternals.com/forum_posts.asp?TID=18909) was asked by someone related to this question, but I thought I'd link to it anyway to keep the two together.  The thread looks very intriguing, but I suspect that some deep dive spelunking would need to happen to figure this out without access to the MS internals.

Answer (score 3):

Off the top of my head, you might try enumerating all windows with EnumWindows, then in the callback, send WM_GETHOTKEY to each window.

Edit: Apparrently I was wrong about that. [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646279(VS.85).aspx) has more information:

> WM_HOTKEY is unrelated to the WM_GETHOTKEY and WM_SETHOTKEY hot keys. The WM_HOTKEY message is sent for generic hot keys while the WM_SETHOTKEY and WM_GETHOTKEY messages relate to window activation hot keys.

Note: [Here](http://tds.diamondcs.com.au/dse/detection/hotkeys.php) is a program purporting to have the functionality you are looking for. You could try decompiling it.

Comment: The link to the program is now completely broken. What program was that? There are so many times I'd like to figure out which program registered my hotkeys because suddenly they don't work anymore or do annoying new things.

Comment: (Often, the Wayback Machine can help in case of webpage disappearance, but here it also has only mirrored a 404 Not Found: [http://web.archive.org/web/*/tds.diamondcs.com.au/dse/detection/hotkeys.php](http://web.archive.org/web/*/tds.diamondcs.com.au/dse/detection/hotkeys.php) )

Answer (score 1):

Another thread mentions a global NT level keyboard hook:

[Re-assign/override hotkey (Win + L) to lock windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/301053/re-assign-override-hotkey-win-l-to-lock-windows)

maybe you can get the handle of the process that called the hook that way, which you can then resolve to the process name

(disclaimer: I had it in my bookmarks, haven't really tried/tested)

Answer (score 1):

I know you can intercept the stream of messages in any window within your own process - what we used to call subclassing in VB6.  (Though I do not remember the function, perhaps SetWindowLong?)  I am unsure if you can do this for windows outside your own process.  But for the sake of this post lets assume you find a way to do that.  Then you can simply intercept the messages for all top level windows, monitor for the WM_HOTKEY message.  You wouldn't be able to know all the keys right off the bat, but as they were pressed you could easily figure out what application was using them.  If you persisted your results to disk and reloaded each time your monitor application was run you could increase the performance of your application over time.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't exactly answer the part of the question that is about the Windows API, but it answers the part of the question that is about a list of global hotkeys and the applications that "own" them.

The free Hotkey Explorer at http://hkcmdr.anymania.com/ shows a list of all global hotkeys and the applications that own them. This just has helped me figure out why an application-specific shortcut key stopped working and how to fix it (by reconfiguring the registered global hotkey in the app that had it registered), within a few seconds.

Comment: installed it and it acted like a virus al at least a program with mall-intend, like a bad joke. Opening all kind of windows, activating voice narator, etc.

Comment: @Flion: See discussion on http://superuser.com/a/191090/3617 .  Basically, some hotkey utilties work by probing every possible key combination.  On Windows 8+, (and to a lesser extent on Windows 7), this probing technique *triggers* every key combination, rather than merely querying it.

Comment: @Flion FWIW, I used it on Win7 with success. But if I understand Brian correctly, this may not work as well with later versions, and how well it works may also depend on custom hotkeys that are defined.