# Visual Studio won't recognize key combination

Tags: visual-studio, keyboard-shortcuts

I'm not sure what could be causing this, but I installed GhostDoc and the default key combination of <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> worked as expected for quite some time.  Recently it just plain stopped for no known reason (there were updates installed, but none related to .NET or Visual Studio that I'm aware of).  Looking under `Tools` -> `Options` -> `Environment` -> `Keyboard`, I'm still seeing the value mapped to the `Tools.SubMain.GhostDoc.DocumentThis` command.  Although when I try pressing the key combination in the "Press shortcut keys:" textbox it doesn't register it.  It registers other Ctrl+Shift+... combinations, just not with <kbd>D</kbd>.

Has anybody else experienced this before?  Any possible solutions (hopefully not involving resetting all keyboard shortcuts)?

Comment: This just happened to me as well. I know that it's a problem inside VS because if I run `Tools.SubMain.GhostDoc.DocumentThis` inside the Command Window, I get: Command "Tools.SubMain.GhostDoc.DocumentThis" is not available. But I can run it from `Tools->GhostDoc` with no problem. I'll try a reboot and see if that works for me too.

Comment: Hope this helps someone. My problem was the rdp software I was using had hijacked the ctrl+shift and ctrl+alt combos.  I was able to resolve with the on-screen keyboard.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is it possible you have another application running that uses the same key combination? It happened to me with Winamp global keys.

Check out [this app](http://elitefreeware.blogspot.com/2009/05/see-which-global-hotkeys-are-active-in.html) tough it can't display which app has registered an active hotkey. I haven't tried it, but if it detects current assigned key combinations you could remove running apps to determine which one uses <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd>.
They have an [open question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/829007/find-out-what-process-registered-a-global-hotkey-windows-api) on Stack Overflow about determining who has what registered.
Some answers there reference other apps that might help you - [this](http://tds.diamondcs.com.au/dse/detection/hotkeys.php), maybe?.

Comment: If Shortcuts page in Tools->Options doesn't react to Ctrl+Shift+D anymore, this is almost certainly a global hotkey.

Comment: Granted it's more of a SuperUser question, but any ideas how to find what could be trapping it?  I launched Key Jedi and it's seeing the key combination while inside Visual Studio. So I'm not sure what could be preventing VS from seeing it.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the apps.  ActiveHotKeys pointed out that something was attached to the combination, but no matter what processes I killed it remained attached.  A system reboot (which I had done before anyways) cleared it up.