# Navigate To (CTRL + comma) in Visual Studio does not work

Tags: visual-studio

The "Navigate To" function (CTRL + comma) does not work on my solution. It gets stuck on "Found 0 matching results" while the little progress bar stays there but is empty.

I searched for some kind of IntelliSense cache file next to the .sln, but all I found was a .suo file which I deleted but it did not help.

Why is it not working?

Comment: Did you solve the problem?  I tried everything including re-installation of Visual Studio, without success.

Comment: I tried everything. Disabled all extensions, uninstalled resharper, ncrunch, kitchen & sink.  Last resort system restore to before recent windows update brought it back to life.  Now to find out what was the cause.

Answer (score 38):

I had the same problem. I went to Tools > Options... > Environment > Keyboard and clicked Reset. Yes, it will reset any customizations you had, but I figured that was the problem for me (I had an add-in take over Ctrl-, and even when I disabled the add-in it wasn't working). Resetting the keyboard shortcut customizations did the trick.

Answer (score 24):

The command is not "Navigate To" but actually `Edit.GotoAll` and it has the keyboard shortcuts of <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>T</kbd> and the more known one of <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>,</kbd> (comma).

*Reference [Default keyboard shortcuts in Visual Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/default-keyboard-shortcuts-in-visual-studio?view=vs-2019)*

---

Solution

Here are the steps to resolve

1. Verify it is working by trying the opposite keyboard shortcut. If both shortcuts do not work type in "Edit Goto All" in the command search/execute box of Visual Studio.

[image: View of the operations search dialog]

- Does the command work? If it does *not* work then do a reset via Visual Studio `Options`:

[image: View of the options dialog]

3. Then verify or add the keyboard command to the command in the mapping after the reset.

- Type in "Edit.Goto" in the `Window commands containing`
- Then selected `Edit.Goto.All`:

[image]

**If you do not see the mapping (#3)**

4. Add the keystroke in the box where bubble 4 is above and **click** `Assign`.
5. Set OK as shown on bubble step 5.

Answer (score 4):

The Navigate To Feature does not use an on disk cache so that shouldn't be the issue.

The only thing I can think of that would cause this behavior is a bad Visual Studio install.  I hate making this suggestion but have you tried repairing the install?

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I'm going to try it.

Answer (score 4):

This is for Chinese user only. This is because of the Sogou Pinyin (搜狗输入法）occupy this shortcut system wide. And it won't release if you just uninstall it.

Go to here to disable it: Language->Advanced settings->Change language bar hot keys

Uninstall it is not working, you need disable that setting then uninstall it.

Answer (score 3):

Tools > Options... > Environment > Keyboard and clicked Reset. That will work.

If you installed the latest version/framework or re-sharper of visual studio then it may happens...

Comment: You can also just go to ReSharper itself and tell it not to set keyboard shortcuts.

Answer (score 1):

I just got the same problem and solve it by following the instruction I found here: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vssetup/thread/2bbab30e-3188-406b-b492-eabf8c2fbc0b/

Comment: Worked for me. I disabled the Default Browser Switcher and it worked again. Funny thing was that when I re-enabled the Default Browser Switcher, everything still worked. Probably some glitch during an update of the extension.

Answer (score 1):

For Chinese users, if you are using Sogou Pinyin, you can turn off Ctrl + Comma thru this.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use `spyxx_amd64.exe` in this answer should work for most cases. https://stackoverflow.com/a/43645062/1179950

However, this didn't work for me... For my case, which is caused by language keyboard hotkey setting in Windows. By Sougou Pinyin though I have uninstalled it..

You can unset this in Control Panal (Windows 10):
Region&Language -> Advanced keyboard settings -> Language bar options ->Advanced Key settings panel

Unset all hotkeys you wont use!

Answer (score 0):

For traditional Chinese users, you muse use the old version  of new Cangjie.

[Ctrl+Comma](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CZvLE.png)