# Visual Studio Ability to Search Everywhere

Tags: visual-studio, search, keyboard-shortcuts

In Visual Studio is there a "Search Everywhere" shortcut (like Resharpers "Search Everywhere")?

I'd prefer to not install Resharper for this, but how can a *search everywhere* be done in Visual Studio?

Comment: Just posting back here a year later. I've found Rider to be much better than VS if you can get your hands on a license. You'll still need VS to do certain things, so a license to both is preferable.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I use the `Navigate To` *(Edit-GotoAll in VS)* command which is <kbd>CTRL</kbd> - <kbd>,</kbd> (comma) or <kbd>CTRL</kbd> - <kbd>T</kbd> which can search for types/files and other info based on the name.

See [Visual Studio Tip #3: Use “Navigate To”](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/benwilli/2015/04/09/visual-studio-tip-3-use-navigate-to/)

---

Otherwise a more limited and historical *way of searching all* is <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>F</kbd> which is find all that they based `Navigate To` on.

---

###### *Navigate To* hidden feature

The best kept secret is to *search using casing*. It is done by typing in just the capitals of the class you search. Example typing "**RFC**" would then find the constructor of the class which had that pascal casing of **R**olands**F**irst**C**lass(); *quite handy*.

###### Key Mappings Do Not Work for Navigate To

Note if you are here about the "Navigate To" feature (actually `Edit.GotoAll`) and <kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>,</kbd> (Comma) or <kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>T</kbd> is not working, I have a visual answer to set/fix the keystrokes here:

[Fix Navigate To Missing KeyMappings](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62862618/285795)

###### Filtering Out files for Navigate To/Edit Goto All

[Visual Studio (Go to All) - How to ignore bin and obj folders](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68213030/visual-studio-go-to-all-how-to-ignore-bin-and-obj-folders/71297949?noredirect=1#comment126248006_71297949)

Comment: I don't know why, but `Ctrl` + `,` does nothing in my vanilla install. Do I have to map it? (I even disabled VIM and it was still doing nothing)

Comment: I remember having to map it too..now that one's settings travel to versions, I only did it once. But CTRL comma makes sense because (for me) its close to ctrl space operation.

Comment: Oh shoot, I wonder if having Resharper install in 2017 caused my `.editorconfig` to be overwritten. Let me try to reset keymap to default and see if that works

Comment: Good luck...we are all counting on you. ;-)

Comment: Yep, resetting the defaults worked. `Ctrl` + `,` works.

Comment: Glad to help a fellow Coloradoan. I'm in HR south of Denver.

Comment: Not sure if it's just me, but on my VS2019 instance the command is called Goto All and no keys were mapped for it. Tools > Optgions > Keyboard > Show commands containing 'GotoAll' and then assign your favoured shortcut (ALT+T for me coming from R#). Also that search for the capitals thing mentioned in the answer is a brilliant idea, didn't know it existed!

Comment: Unfortunately using this way, it's impossible to search text. Like something you want to find in a .json file for example. This method only searches code. Resharper searches everywhere.