# Visual Studio (Go to All) - How to ignore bin and obj folders

Tags: c#, visual-studio, uwp

I want Go to All (Ctrl + ,) to ignore bin and obj folders, or at least ignore .g.* files.  Can I do either or both?

Here is a picture of a basic UWP app without source control. bin and obj folders are excluded from the Solution, however, .g files from the generated directories are still included in search with Go to All.

[image]

Comment: I have a similar need, but for a Blazor project.  I never want to see .g.cs files in Go To All; is there any way to filter them out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Filter by the `Files` button (or keyboard chord <kbd>Ctrl-1</kbd>,<kbd>Ctrl-F</kbd>)

[image]

Comment: Ah, that does what I need, thanks. I'll remap the shortcut to something more convenient.

Comment: @PatrickSzalapski in case you missed it.

Comment: Not quite right...I still want to "go to files or types or members" like the default search, just without the types in g.cs files.