# Hide g.i.cs files from Go To All in Visual Studio 2022

Tags: wpf, visual-studio-2022

I use **Edit / Go To All** heavily (shortcut: ctrl + ,), but what is quite annoying is, that the .g.i.cs files show up and even as first results:

[image: GoToAllProblem]

Is there an option to hide those files?

Comment: Similar: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68213030/visual-studio-go-to-all-how-to-ignore-bin-and-obj-folders

Comment: Thanks - but as in the comments in the of the answer: I use it mostly to search for members and the solution with the file filter does not help

Answer (score 2):

Apparently this is still not possible, as the issue is open in gituhub:

["Go to type" tool includes .g.i.cs files, should not #26369](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/26369)