# Is it possible to block WIN+L on windows using c++

Tags: c, windows, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts

I am writing a such application in which i am need to block/disable the some shortcut keys like

> WIN+L, WIN+G , Alt+Ctrl+Del,

ect...

we have already similar questions available on stack overflow but no one provided exact answer.

1. Is it possible ?
2. How?

I tried using `LowLevelKeyboardProc` but no luck, other normal shortcut is blocking like Alt+Tab...

Comment: Could you post the code for your `LowLevelKeyboardProc` as the code to block key combinations is non-trivial.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Re-assign/override hotkey (Win + L) to lock windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/301053/re-assign-override-hotkey-win-l-to-lock-windows)